# apt-get error, cannot install many packages?

Tags: apt, error-handling, crossover

How do I fix this? It shows an error, and I don't know how to fix it. I want to install crossover.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 crossover:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libice6:i386 but it is not installed or
                           xlibs:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libsm6:i386 but it is not installed or
                           xlibs:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installed or
                           xlibs:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installed or
                           xlibs:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libz1:i386
                  Depends: perl5-base:i386
                  Depends: perl-modules:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: python:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
                  Depends: python-gtk2:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: python-glade2:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: desktop-file-utils:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libasound2:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libgl1:i386
                  Depends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

---

**EDIT**

I have another recent error.

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 crossover:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3) but it is not installed
                  Depends: libice6:i386 but it is not installed or
                           xlibs:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libsm6:i386 but it is not installed or
                           xlibs:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libx11-6:i386 but it is not installed or
                           xlibs:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libxext6:i386 but it is not installed or
                           xlibs:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libfreetype6:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libz1:i386
                  Depends: perl5-base:i386
                  Depends: perl-modules:i386 but it is not installable
                  Depends: python:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
                  Depends: python-gtk2:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: python-glade2:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: desktop-file-utils:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libasound2:i386 but it is not installed
                  Depends: libgl1:i386
                  Depends: libxrandr2:i386 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

running `apt-get -f install` gives me the same error every time.

Comment: What is the exact command you executed? And as which user?

Comment: I used this command: sudo apt-get -f install I used the user which I have created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem myself.

Just run :

> sudo apt-get autoremove crossover:i386

and reinstall.